# Hibernate ignoring my dialect

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to use hibernate for postreSQL but it doesn't work.
I put the .xml to 'resources' folder.

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="ru.systemprom.example.testClass"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

During the starting i get wrong info:

```
22:09:43,646 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] Database ->
       name : HSQL Database Engine
    version : 1.8.0
      major : 1
      minor : 8
22:09:43,646 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] Driver ->
       name : HSQL Database Engine Driver
    version : 1.8.0
      major : 1
      minor : 8
22:09:43,692 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect // !? i setted up posgresSQL dialect not hsql =(
22:09:43,719 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader] Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
```

I think Hibernate doesn't work because of this error occurs.
Why does it ignoring my settings and how to let it work?

Note: I heard Maven takes everything from 'resources' folder so i think the problem isn't because of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your code for creating the session factory? Ensure that you are passing it the configuration file...
configure() can take a string, Document, file, url, etc.

```
new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
```